# Android check if internet connection receives data/packets

Tags: android, networking

I have seen a lot of answers that respond to only one question: "check if an internet connection is available".
Although, I want to find out how to check if data/packets is/are sent over that internet connection.
Do you have any ideas on how to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:

case 1 for wi-fi connection:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifiNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
boolean hasWiFiConnection = (wifiNetInfo != null) && wifiNetInfo.isConnected();
return hasWiFiConnection;
```

case 2 for mobile connecton:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mobileNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean hasMobileConnection = (mobileNetInfo != null) && mobileNetInfo .isConnected();
return hasMobileConnection;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this::

```
 boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
            Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
            method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
            // get the setting for "mobile data"
            mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Some problem accessible private API
            // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
        }
```

Comment: The code that you provided only checks if mobile data is enabled and not if there are any data packets being received.